# 2 DHCP Server it is possible to set a default server and a second

Tags: dhcp, dhcp-server

i have the following question (Problem)

i have a AVM Fritzbox 7390 as WLAN Router and there is DHCP-service running with a range of 50 adresse.
so far i works nice.

Know i would like to have a PXE server in my network.
On the Fritzbox i can't do the definition of a PXE-Server IP Adresse.

so i thought i could add a second DCHP Server with another Range of 50 Adress on the PXE-Server itself.

So know how it is possible to convinc a client to use the PXE-DHCP-Server if this is online and the fritzbox if the PXE-DHCP-Server is offline?

Just to switch off the Fritzbox-DHCP is not really a option because i will be losing all Port forward rules. From the AVM Support Center you don't get a useful feedback. A solution would be to hack the Fritzbox - but it is not to much a solution too

Comment: You can setup a [proxy DHCP server that hands out the PXE information](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/186302/fedora-network-install-via-pxe-boot). This works nicely in combination with a FritzBox.

Answer (score 1):

You can have several DHCP servers on your network, but you cannot set a priority.  Addressless clients will broadcast to find one, and will then choose one however they like (usually whichever replies first) and accept its offer.

I suggest that if your existing DHCP server is using its lease data to support anything (port forwarding as you mentioned and maybe dynamic rDNS), that may not work reliably if you add a second DHCP server.

As long as they don't share the same range of IPs, it is possible for them to be authoritative for their own scope (but not the subnet, or globally).  Otherwise, or if this configuration can't be specified with  your software, neither may be authoritative; this might cause problems for roaming clients connecting to your wireless network.  In particular, if they have an RFC1918 address in your subnet assigned while they were elsewhere, for example, they would not get a `DHCPNAK` when attempting to renew the lease.